# Sequential LED turn signal

Tags: led, circuit-design, comparator, 555, power-sequencing

I am trying to build a 4 LED sequential turn signal using the ne555 timer module and some comparators. I am having trouble with my next steps when trying to figure out what is wrong with my design. Below is a picture of my schematic. In falstad, it works exactly how I would want it to work. In real life, after actually ordering components and putting it together on a bread board, all of the LEDs turn on and stay on. I am assuming this has something to do with my comparator resistors not being at the right value. At first glance, is there something I am missing or doing wrong? Advice on where to go would be greatly appreciated. The switch next to the 10uF capacitor is to imitate what the 10uF should be doing in real life. I believe falstad only uses ideal capacitors so they are always charged. I am open to different designs as well. This will eventually be used to power LEDs with a fwdV of 2.9V @ 350mA. [image]

Comment: So you are making a high going pulse that "slowly" rises and the comparators will change their output as the voltage of the pulse rises.  In real life, what does the voltage ramp look like?

Comment: What comparator and transistors did you use for the build?

Comment: The time constant of 1k and 10u is 10 milliseconds (neglecting the current stolen by opamp inputs). Let's assume that this duration is divided into 3 equal time slots for each sequence: 3.3ms = 300Hz. The human eye can catch lower than 20-25Hz, so you cannot distinguish the sequential illumination of the LEDs. Plus, you should always be careful while working with breadboards.

Comment: @Aaron For the comparator, I am using the LM2902N and I am using BT169D,112. (Ordered these off of mouser).

Comment: @RohatKılıç So, you are saying that it could be working but it could be switching so fast that it just looks on to me?

Comment: @RohatKılıç So a 10k resistor and a 7uF capacitor would be more realistic because this would give me 14Hz, which I would be able to see. Correct?

Comment: @Myles Still too high freq., because the comparators has set the compare voltage too low (divider 510,390:10k ), the last one is switched at ~2v, so you are using 20% of bottom part of "ramp" only. Change this thresholds, or use 100u cap.

Comment: @Myles Also check the 555 frequency, seems to high to me.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický Where would the 100u cap go? would it replace the 10uF capacitor? I pulled this a stable ne555 off of falstad. When doing the math is says its output pulse width is 21 seconds. That is weird. I calculated different values to have it HIGH for 1 second, but that doesnt simulate correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I converted your negative image into a normal positive, then cropped and enlarged it.
Your 1k feeding the capacitor, 10k feeding the resistor divider, 510 and 390 ohms resistor values are 20 times too low.
[image: sequential]

Comment: Okay, I will order those components and try that out. Why are they 20 times to low? Wondering so I can understand what I am doing.

Comment: When I simulate that in falstad, none of it works. The resistance in the 1k and 10k when upped by 20 times is too large for current to flow.